# How to properly use open gl calls with libGDX

Tags: java, opengl, libgdx

I am trying to render a terrain using my own shader and by using low level open gl methods.
But other parts of the game use SpriteBatch and other GDXlib render classes.

My openGL code for terrain renders correctly until I make a call to:

```
spriteBatch.draw(...);
```

or something similar like:

```
stage.draw();
```

After that call, my openGL code just not draw anymore. No error, just nothing on screen.
But SpriteBatch works just OK.

After a loooong time, I figured out that I need to call

```
glEnableVertexAttribArray(...);
```

and

```
Gdx.gl.glBindBuffer(GL20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, posVertexBufferLoc);
Gdx.gl.glVertexAttribPointer(positionAttribLoc, 4, GL20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
```

**I NEED TO CALL IT BEFORE I CALL -> glDrawArrays(...);**

***EVERY TIME BEFORE I USE glDraw... , ->  EVERY FRAME***

If I don't call first one, nothing is rendered.

If I don't call second one, it renders at the wrong positions.

It looks like everytime I use GDXlib classes to render, it somehow messes my attributes up.

*Init code:*

```
shaderProgram = new ShaderProgram(baseVertexShader, baseFragmentShader);
if (!shaderProgram.isCompiled()) {
    Gdx.app.error("TerrainRenderer - Cannot compile shader", shaderProgram.getLog());
}

shaderProgram.begin();

//vertexBuffers
vertexBuffer = BufferUtils.newFloatBuffer(quadPosVertices.length);
vertexBuffer.put(quadPosVertices);
vertexBuffer.rewind();
//VBOs
//generate buffers
posVertexBufferLoc = Gdx.gl.glGenBuffer();
//pass data into buffers
Gdx.gl.glBindBuffer(GL20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, posVertexBufferLoc);
Gdx.gl.glBufferData(GL20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer.capacity()*4, vertexBuffer, GL20.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
//attributes
//locations
positionAttribLoc = shaderProgram.getAttributeLocation("position");
//attributes specifications
Gdx.gl.glBindBuffer(GL20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, posVertexBufferLoc);
Gdx.gl.glVertexAttribPointer(positionAttribLoc, 4, GL20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
//enabling attributes
shaderProgram.enableVertexAttribute(positionAttribLoc);
//end shader
shaderProgram.end();
Gdx.gl.glBindBuffer(GL20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0); //unbind
```

*Draw code:*

```
Gdx.gl.glBindBuffer(GL20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, posVertexBufferLoc);
Gdx.gl.glVertexAttribPointer(positionAttribLoc, 4, GL20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

shaderProgram.enableVertexAttribute(positionAttribLoc);

shaderProgram.begin();
Gdx.gl.glDrawArrays(GL20.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
shaderProgram.end();
Gdx.gl.glBindBuffer(GL20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

***So What is the correct way to use openGL methods with GDXlib classes?
Do I really need to call those attribute functions every frame?***

Comment: Which OpenGL version do you use? In OpenGL 3.0 you can use [Vertex Array Objects](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Array_Object)

Comment: According to this: https://www.badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=25760
It sould be 4.1, if I understand it correcly.
But the question is -> Can learn an use VAO's solve my issue?

Comment: Yes. A VAO stores the vertex specification. it is sufficient to bind the VAO before the draw call. Note, if you don't use a named VAO, then automatically the default VAO (0) is used and the vertex specification is stored in the default VAO.

Comment: You’re going lower level than you need to. You can use the Mesh class for this and it will properly bind and unbind so you aren’t borrowing and messing with your SpriteBatch’s mesh.

Comment: @Tenfour04
I know, but I've thought this should work too...

Comment: @Tenfour04
Rendering using Mesh instance works!

Comment: Great, sorry I didn't get a chance to look at specifics. There might be some detail about something that needed to be bound/unbound that the Mesh class is doing for you but that you accidentally omitted in your own code.

Comment: @Tenfour04, @Rabbid76, 
I've found out that `Mesh.class` calls:
`glBindBuffer(GL20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, location)`
`glVertexAttribPointer(...)` and 
`glEnableVertexAttribArray(...)`, before **every** draw call.
I looks to me like GDXlib doesn't use VAO's for some reason, and therefore it needs to be called every frame.
Am I right?
Is there any performance impact calling it before every draw call?

Comment: How can `mesh.draw(...)`, destroy my attribute setup? It doesn't even use the same shader?

Comment: @JerryLundegaard That has nothing to do with the shader. The vertex specification is stored in a VAO. If you don't use different named VAOs, then the default VAO (0) is reused for each mesh. If you use the same VAO, then you have to change the vertex specification before each draw call.

Comment: @Rabbid76
Oh, I thought that `glGetAttribLocation(program, name)` returns different location number for the attribute, because it uses different shader, but you are right, it doesn't. Now it makes sense to me. The mesh uses the same location numbers for its attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenGL is a state machine. When libGDX is doing something with OpenGL it will inevitably change the state of the OpenGL context to something different.

The *canonical* way to draw stuff in OpenGL is:

1. Set every state you depend on to the values you need for drawing.
2. Then draw it.

For the longest time OpenGL didn't have VAOs (vertex array objects) and you had in fact to do a glBindBuffer, glVertexAttribPointer combo every time you switched vertex buffers. Most OpenGL drivers are well optimized in that code path, and for a matter of fact, back when when VAOs got introduced, using them impaired performance. That's no longer the case, but it used to be.

Also you can't improve performance by "saving" on OpenGL calls. OpenGL isn't *that* low level and in many ways operates a lot like a modern out-of-order-execution CPU: As long as the outcome is identical to what would render if every command was done in order it can delay and rearrange operations.